# Running Spring MVC app with jetty-runner on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jetty, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am moving my Spring MVC app that uses hibernate from heroku to Amazon. The app works perfectly on heroku with;

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

But when upload my war file to my Amazon Beanstalk application I get;

```
no main manifest attribute, in application.jar
```

Since there is no MainClass here as having a ex: EmbeddedServer.java class with a main method that starts the Server, am I wrong to think that its not possible to run this with jetty-runner and I need to go with the MainClass option?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I'll answer my stupid question. As it ended up, creating a Tomcat application instead of a Java Application solved the problem.